# Erro em código básico no Kivy(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-kivy

Fiz um código bem simples usando o Kivy, mas da esse erro que ta mostrando na imagem abaixo:
[image: Erro na hora da execução]
O código é o seguinte:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

if __name__ in ('__android__', '__main__'):
    MyApp().run()
```

Poderiam me explicar o que tem de errado?

Comment: Qual é o código do arquivo `base.py`?

Comment: Anderson, o código é o que está na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

No site oficial da biblioteca Kivy (https://kivy.org/) é possível ver um exemplo de uso. A biblioteca já está na na versão 1.10.0.

O exemplo a seguir vem direto do site oficial e vai exibir um botão "Hello World":

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
      return Button(text = 'Hello World')

MyApp().run()
```

Como pode ver é bem similar ao seu código!

Comment: Poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/255163/edit) e explicar sua resposta ? Ela está entrando na lista de Publicações de Baixa Qualidade.

Comment: Resposta editada! =)

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a pergunta já tem alguns meses, mas se alguém estiver procurando a resposta, está aqui.

Algumas funcionalidades do Kivy necessitam a instalação de dependências, para que essas funcionalidades possam funcionar corretamente. Essas dependências não são instaladas automaticamente para não prejudicar o desempenho da aplicação instalando coisas desnecessárias para o seu projeto, por isso são feitas a parte.

No Guia de Instalação tem a explicação pro que você precisa: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Mas só executando essas duas linhas de comando você já pode obter as principais dependências:

```
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew 
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
```